# Where are the Braille books?

Tags: accessibility, books, vision-impairment

I wonder why it's so difficult to find Braille books. Free software is available to convert text to Braille, why aren't publishers taking advantage of this to automatically convert their books? Do books require manual verification? Am I missing something?

Comment: Since we live in a capitalist society the only actions that are valued as "worth it" are those that help to accrue capital. Unfortunately the market for braille books is too small to be "worth it" for publishers to produce them. 

Publishers (and any other for-profit organisation) do things not because those are the right things to do, but merely because those things are profitable.

Blame capitalism. :)

Comment: And for a less pessimistic (albeit very valid) reason: I suspect the rise of audio books, and huge advances in automatic text-to-speech software has reduced the demand (making it even less likely to be "worth it").

Comment: Voting to close because, interesting though it is, this isn't a UX question.

Comment: @MattObee, no worries. Which Stack forum is a good place to ask a question on accessibility for the disabled? thanks!

Comment: (1) Braille embossers are expensive. (2) The Braille equivalents of printed books are several times bigger than the printed ones. (3) Relatively few blind people actually know Braille. (P.S. I worked at the research group that developed [ODT2Braille](http://odt2braille.sourceforge.net/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note**: I am not blind, or visually impaired. If I've made any erroneous suppositions about what it is to be so, or how effective or useful any of the technologies mentioned below are, I apologize.*

*In a nutshell*: the *need* (although perhaps not the *desire*) for expensive-to-make printed braille books has been greatly reduced by advances in technology, including: audio-books (especially with digital delivery), improvements to text-to-speech / screen-readers and refreshable braille displays.

---

**Audio Books**

From [The Untold Story of the Talking Book](https://www.ft.com/content/43d3f6bc-b71d-11e6-ba85-95d1533d9a62) on FT.com (the website of the UK's *Financial Times* newspaper), in their review of [*The Untold Story of the Talking Book* by Matthew Rubery](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0674545443):

> The talking book in its current form exists thanks to early 20th-century efforts to bring literature to the blind on both sides of the Atlantic. **A Braille book cost 20 times more than a print version**, and in 1930 Helen Keller, the blind author and political activist, implored Congress (successfully) to offer financial support for Braille books. While only a fifth of blind people were able to use Braille, advances in technology meant that within a few years lending libraries of talking books were established.
>
> From 1934 in the US, and a year later in the UK, talking books were recorded on Vinylite and shellac respectively, and various machines were distributed to play the discs. The experience was transformative for many listeners: “I feel like flying over the moon with pleasure,” one wrote.

There are numerous sources around the web attesting to a massive growth in audio-books (e.g. [this statista.com page](https://www.statista.com/statistics/249854/audiobook-industry-size-in-the-us/) shows a US sales growth of over 250% between 2009 and 2017). Even if only a fraction of these sales are *due* to blind or visually-impaired buyers, the growth in the market available to them (both in width of choice, and ease of availability) will drive down the *need* for physical braille books.

---

**Sceen-Readers / Text-to-Speech**

Although the [Wikipedia page on *Speech synthesis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis) includes:

> Early electronic speech-synthesizers sounded robotic and were often barely intelligible. The quality of synthesized speech has steadily improved, but as of 2016 output from contemporary speech synthesis systems remains clearly distinguishable from actual human speech.

the technology behind text-to-speech has improved vastly from the early days. The ability for eBook readers – be they on phones, Kindles (or other dedicated readers), tablets or PCs – to convert the written word to spoken also reduces the need for physical braille books – virtually anything available as an eBook can be accessed by a blind or visually impaired person.

In passing, the ability for eBook readers to scale text on-the-fly also reduces the need for *large / giant print* books.

---

**Refreshable Braille Displays**

[Refreshable braille displays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refreshable_braille_display) are – roughly – the braille-equivalent to a VDU/LCD. Instead of having fixed, printed (embossed?) braille books, they can generate ever-changing braille impressions on-the-fly. According to [Braille and Audio Reading Materials](https://www.loc.gov/nls/braille-audio-reading-materials/) on the *National Library Service for the Blind and Print Disabled* (part of the US Library of Congress):

> Patrons may download braille and talking books through the Braille and Audio Reading Download (BARD), a web-based service that provides access to thousands of braille and talking books, magazines, and music scores available. Braille and talking books and magazines may be also downloaded through the BARD Mobile app, which requires connection to a refreshable braille display via a Bluetooth connection.

so those who *do* prefer to "read" braille, have an avenue to do so, without needing physical braille books.

---

**Other Factors**

The ability to read braille has declined over the years, making what was probably never a profit-generating exercise (producing physical braille books) even less attractive. According to the page [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille) on Wikipedia, the situation in the US is:

> In 1960, 50% of legally blind, school-age children were able to read braille in the U.S.[15][16] According to the 2015 Annual Report from the American Printing House for the Blind, there were 61,739 legally blind students registered in the U.S. Of these, 8.6% (5,333) were registered as braille readers, 31% (19,109) as visual readers, 9.4% (5,795) as auditory readers, 17% (10,470) as pre-readers, and 34% (21,032) as non-readers.

and in the UK the proportion of braille readers is only around 1%:

> Though braille is thought to be the main way blind people read and write, in Britain (for example) out of the reported two million blind and low vision population, it is estimated that only around 15,000–20,000 people use braille. Younger people are turning to electronic text on computers with screen reader software instead, a more portable communication method that they can use with their friends. A debate has started on how to make braille more attractive and for more teachers to be available to teach it.